# Regex to count characters

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to verify the number of | in the line of a file. In this example it checks for exactly 5 bars.

```
^[\|]{5}$
```

This verifies 5, but doesn't take into account/ignore other characters.

```
Dice|Puppy|Button|Sunny|Music|Extra
```

What am I missing? Regex always throws me off.

Comment: You say you want to check for 5 pipes and you do.  The rest of your question is vague.  What do you want to account for or ignore?

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit more? that regex you wrote will match a line with 5 pipes and nothing else.

Comment: I just want to verify that the string above has exactly 5 pipes. If it has more or less, the regex should be invalid.

Comment: That regex matches the string `|||||`. Perhaps regex is not the right too for the job?

Comment: The regex needs to be able to ignore the text between pipes. It just needs to verify that the entire string (words and pipes) contains only 5 pipes. Currently the regex I wrote above will fail due to the characters between the pipes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[^|]*(\|[^|]*){4}$
```

Comment: OOPS! Just realized my puppy example only had four pipes. Either way, you were correct!

Comment: What about when on occasion, you do need there to be a blank inbetween? This regex will not work for this case

Comment: This would handle one or the other. ^([\|]{5}|[^|]+(\|[^|]+){5})$ But if your string has 23 pipes in it, it would be really silly to try to write out every permutation.

Comment: @Atomiklan fair enough about blanks. Edited regex to allow blank terms (just changed `+` to `*`)

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of pipes:

```
line='Dice|Puppy|Button|Sunny|Music'
npipes="$(echo "$line" | tr -c -d '|' | wc -c)"
```

To test that the number of pipes is 5:

```
[ "$(echo "$line" | tr -c -d '|' | wc -c)" -eq 5 ] && echo success
```

In this approach, translate (`tr`) is used to remove all characters except pipe. (It deletes (`-d`) the everything but (`-c`) the pipe character).  Then, word count (`wc`) is used to count the number of bytes (`-c`).  This number can be compared against 5 using a standard bash equality test (`-eq`).